# Show only the relationships of selected node in network visualization graph

Tags: d3.js, vis.js, graph-visualization, angular-chart, vis.js-network

I have imeplemented a network graph like below image using `vis.js` library. 
[image]

When a user clicks/double-clicks on particular node I want to show the relationships of only that particular node.

Is there any way to do that using `vis.js` library. If not is there any other `graph visualization` library which I can make use of?

[VIS network sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-vis-graph)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the nodes which are shown on the network by converting them into a DataView and adding a subscription to the network to watch for double clicks (which will allow you to trigger the filter).  Details can be found [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-data/data/dataview.html#Subscriptions) with an example [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/dynamicFiltering.html).

The list of events which you can subscribe to can be found [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events) with details of the object passed from the event.

Hope this helps!